# Android strange dimension behaviour with multiple screen size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support

I am finishing my first android application and I am now taking the time to optimize the app for different screen sizes.

I created 5 drawable and 5 values folders (default + mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi). By playing around with the images called by my animation-list (present in all the drawable folders except the default) I confirmed that the emulator calls the drawable-mdpi (although it should be calling hdpi since the emulador is for the Nexus One 3.7" which is hdpi - I don't know why this happens).

The other problem is that when using @dimen inside my ring_background.xml, the emulator calls the default values folder(I confirmed by changing the values in all folders and check which influenced the drawn shape), ignoring both mdpi and hdpi folders.

Finally I leave here an image of my project folders just to know if it is done correctly.[image]

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily trust the emulator configuration for this. Try a real device to be sure.

Comment: :S I don't have a wide range of android phones to test all the screen sizes